# Where to put drawrect in cellforrowatindexpath?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, drawrect

It seems to work much faster to do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    JHomeViewCell *cell = (JHomeViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[JHomeViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.cellContent.thumbnailCache = self.thumbnailCache;
    }

    Entry *entry = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.cellContent.entry != entry) {
        [cell.cellContent setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

The problem is when an entry is edited, the cell doesn't change. I could check for all elements of the cell, to see if they're different, but is there a better way of doing this? Calling drawrect every time the cell appears slows the app down and seems unnecessary.

Comment: Why did you edit the code in the question, after you got an answer, to be what the answer suggested?  Which is your real code? With `drawRect:` or `setNeedsDisplay`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do custom drawing for your tableview cell you have to subclass `UITableViewCell` (as it looks you have done with `JHomeViewCell`).

Put drawRect inside of your implementation of JHomeViewCell

```
@implementation JHomeviewCell

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect];
    // Insert drawing code here
}

@end
```

Also, you shouldn't call drawRect directly. You should call `setNeedsDisplay` instead, and probably need to set the cellContent.entry value to the entry you have from your results controller.

```
Entry *entry = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.cellContent.entry != entry) {
    cell.cellContent.entry = entry;
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I've put it inside a subview of the cell because if i put it as as subview of the cell, it'd go right to the back and would be hidden behind other cell content, such as it's background, which is a uiview itself.

Comment: That should work too, just make sure you set the `cellContent.entry` to `entry` and call `setNeedsDisplay` instead of `drawRect`.

Comment: Thank you! `setNeedsDisplay` worked perfectly for my case!